# Not able to consume javafx htmleditor keyevent when launched with JDialog

Tags: javafx, keyevent, html-editor

```
public class CustomizedHTMLEditor extends HTMLEditor
{
    public CustomizedHTMLEditor()
    {
        addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.U && event.isAltDown()) {
                System.out.println("Alt+U is pressed");
                event.consume();
                event.isShortcutDown();
                final KeyCode platformShortcutKey = Toolkit.getToolkit().getPlatformShortcutKey();
                System.out.println(platformShortcutKey.getName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

#### Process 1:

```
public class CustomizedHTMLEditorMain extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        CustomizedHTMLEditor customizedHTMLEditor = new CustomizedHTMLEditor();
        customizedHTMLEditor.setFocusTraversable(true);
        customizedHTMLEditor.requestFocus();
        customizedHTMLEditor.toFront();

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(customizedHTMLEditor));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

#### Process 2:

```
public class CutomizedHTMLPanel extends JDialog
{

    CutomizedHTMLPanel()
    {
        PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {

        });
        PlatformImpl.runAndWait(() -> {
            final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(new CustomizedHTMLEditor()));
            add(new JPanel().add(jfxPanel));
            pack();
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final CutomizedHTMLPanel panel = new CutomizedHTMLPanel();
        panel.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        panel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When I press ALT+U in the editor:
In the process 1, event is consumed successfully and no Character("U" in this case) is typed in the editor.
In the process 2, Character is being typed in the editor.

I want to use shortcut ALT+U in process 2, and when we press ALT+U, no character should be typed.